# How to customize the edges in networkx?

Tags: python-2.7, customization, networkx, graphviz, edge-list

I want to make some customize edges in networkx. These edges should be like those on the column labeled as symbol of the following table (excepting the 13 row):

[image]

Anyone can please give some clues in how to build it?
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE 1: Looks like graphviz can do that:

[graphviz arrow-shapes](http://graphviz.org/content/arrow-shapes)

[look for the Attribute Type Descriptions](http://graphviz.org/content/attrs)

But graphviz is based on C instead python, and it go beyond my knowledge. However, networkx can handle with graphviz objects. There should be a doc about this at somewhere...

Comment: Is this a question about how to display edges with networkx so that they look like what you've got?  Or how to store the edges as different types so that algorithms know how to treat them differently?  Simply: is your desired output here a figure that people look at or a data structure that the computer will use?

Comment: @Joel The first one: display edges and output a figure that people look.

Answer (score 0):

ummm

```
G.add_edge('C','D',arrowhead="diamond")
```

?

Comment: Nope. There is not any edge with diamond shape... and the code does not return any error.

Comment: maybe it is supposed to use the arrowhead attribute instead?

Comment: It looks like thats the case based on http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@s@u@Supybot-plugins-HEAD@WebStats@plugin.py/484/pygraphviz.AGraph.add_edge

Comment: typically I just output a raw dot file and dont mess with this type of wrapper ... its easy enough ...